# Shirt.size is not updating as intended to do so

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am currently using a endpoint to hit my database and retrieve a picture for me depending on what the user selects, this all works fine but when the user selects one color nothing happens, then they select the other color and the first choice finally appears, so its like in reverse. I know this is probably caused with something to do with the render of the page and the update of the object state but i cant figure out how to get it fixed, here is my current code.

My state:

```
//Keeps track of color user selects
  const [color, setColor] = useState("white");
```

My updateInCart which is called upon when the user clicks a color:

```
//Updates state color of shirt being selected
  const updateColor = async (userColor, shirt) => {
    setColor(userColor);

    const shirtColorSource = await fetch(
      `http://localhost:5000/products/${shirt.product_id}/${color}`
    );
    const shirtColor = await shirtColorSource.json();
    shirt.image = shirtColor[0].image;
    console.log(shirt.image);

  };
```

My useEffect() function which i believe is not working properly rn:

```
useEffect(() => {
    updateColor("white", shirt);
    console.log("IN EFFECT");
  }, [color])
```

How i display the image:

```
{shirt.map((shirt) => (
        <div key={shirt.product_id} className="row">
          <div className="col-md-12 col-lg-4 ml-auto">
            <img
              src={shirt.image}
              alt={shirt.name}
              className="img-responsive w-100"
            />
          </div>
```

Im just curious the best way in having the image update accurately to the user.

Edit: Forgot to put where the color is actually selected:

```
<div className="row justify-content-center">
                  <button
                    onClick={() => updateColor("white", shirt)}
                    className="button button5 ml-lg-4"
                  >
                    {" "}
                  </button>
                  <button
                    onClick={() => updateColor("black", shirt)}
                    className="button button5 bg-dark mr-lg-4 ml-md-5 mr-md-5"
                  >
                    {" "}
                  </button>
                </div>
```

This is also how shirt is defined, using a prop of products which comes from the database:

```
const { shirtName } = useParams();
  const shirt = products.filter((product) => product.name === shirtName);
```

Comment: Why does an effect depending on the color to change change the color itself?

Comment: Also if shirt.image is supposed to change and the ui depends on it, it shall be in a state.

Comment: You're setting the color in the useEffect of the color state? setColor should be somewhere else like on a change event on a select. useEffect would then be triggered after the color changes.

Comment: Where/how is `shirt` defined? Is it a state variable? If not then I guess it should be, as per @JonasWilms 's comment

Comment: @AnisR.  I updated the post to answer your questions, The useEffect is not necessary but i needed the code updateColor to run on render

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may coming from your `useEffect`, which does not tell all the truth about its dependencies, and when it sould be executed:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    updateColor(color, shirt);
    console.log("IN EFFECT");
  }, [updateColor, color, shirt])
```

BTW, your function `updateColor` is not `memoized`, so it's a problem if you use it in your `useEffect`. Consider move it into the `useEffect` directly (if not used elsewhere), otherwise declare it with `useCallback`.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const updateColor = async (...) => {
    ...
  };

  updateColor(color, shirt);
  console.log("IN EFFECT");
}, [color, shirt])

// or
const updateColor = useCallback(async (...) => {
  ...
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
  updateColor(color, shirt);
  console.log("IN EFFECT");
}, [updateColor, color, shirt])
```

Comment: Im slightly confused on how to set this up properly, i tried your first method but it did not work and just said "updateColor is not defined"

Comment: Can you provide a sandbox link to your solution?